# How to get HDMI audio working on Intel NUC8i5BEH

Tags: sound, hdmi, intel-nuc

I have an Intel NUC8i5BEH and just did a fresh installed Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS.  I didn't have to do anything special other than install with safe mode graphics (nomodeset).

Everything seems to work just fine except I get no audio over HDMI.  The only Output Device in Setting > Sound is "Headphones - Built-in Audio" when I have something plugged into the 3.5 mm jack.  This is the only playback hardware device listed.  HDMI audio is enabled in the BIOS.  Any ideas on how to get HDMI audio working?

```
$ aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC233 Analog [ALC233 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ hwinfo --short
cpu:                                                            
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz, 3604 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz, 3536 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz, 3522 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz, 3509 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz, 3555 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz, 3433 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz, 3546 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz, 3566 MHz
keyboard:
  /dev/input/event4    Chicony Electronics KU-0833 Keyboard
mouse:
  /dev/input/mice      Logitech M90/M100 Optical Mouse
graphics card:
                       Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655
sound:
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
storage:
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
network:
  wlp0s20f3            Intel Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
  eno1                 Intel Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V
network interface:
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  eno1                 Ethernet network interface
  wlp0s20f3            Ethernet network interface
disk:
  /dev/sda             Samsung SSD 860
partition:
  /dev/sda1            Partition
  /dev/sda2            Partition
usb controller:
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #15
                       Intel 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
hub:
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Genesys Logic Hub
                       ASIX Electronics AX68004
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
bluetooth:
                       Intel Bluetooth Device
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
                       Intel Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM
                       Realtek RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader
                       Intel Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller
  /dev/input/event7    Chicony Electronics KU-0833 Keyboard

$ sudo dmesg | grep -i audio
[    0.272840] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[   64.564460] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: couldn't bind with audio component
[   64.587098] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC233: line_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:hp
[   64.587100] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   64.587101] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   64.587102] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   64.587102] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   64.587104] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[   64.587106] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[   64.660599] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
[   64.661679] hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: Unable to bind the codec
```

Comment: To be clear if headphones plugged into jack HDMI does not have audio?

Comment: @David correct, if headphones are plugged into jack the audio comes through the headphones

Comment: If you remove the headphones does the HDMI audio work?

Comment: @David No, without headphones there is no audio at all.

Comment: Are you sure it works with Ununtu? Here it says windows 10 only. https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/126148/intel-nuc-kit-nuc8i5beh.html

Comment: @David I suppose you're correct in that it's not officially supported.  But everything works well except for audio over hdmi.  If I can get that working then I'd be a happy camper.

Comment: No this solution is more simple and at the same time it can get complicated. I solved the same problem in my audio Interface Settings. Just to see if it works, because I know it will. Boot a new OS, try few different ones, like Slackware try Wifislax specifically. Not all OSs come properly configured as this one does. In this OS you will see many audio interfaces, it doesn't mean one program can run at your OS ,that's ignorance of most people, and MUST have the settings of that program properly configured or created in order to work.

Comment: Don't connect audio jack with HDMI or do so it can appear in the audio settings, once appears you disconnect. Try Pulseaudio first then activate Alsa, however Alsa and Pulseaudio can get trick if you start to mess up both config files. Hence you need that bootable pendrive, so any mess you just restart machine. And yes you can deactivate Alsa and try something more legacy or different

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar NUC at the day job (an 8i7HNK) that had audio issues over HDMI. The solution was to disable `tsched` in PulseAudio's `default.pa` file. From [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index4h3)

> tsched
> **Since 0.9.11**. Use system-timer based model (aka glitch-free). Defaults to `1` (enabled). If your hardware does not return accurate timing information (e.g. Creative sound cards) you can try to set `tsched=0` to enable the interupt (sic) based timing which was used in 0.9.10 and before.

For the 8i7HNK, the returned timing information was incorrect despite not using a Creative sound card.

Here's how to update the `default.pa` file:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Edit PulseAudio's `default.pa` file:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/pulse/default.pa
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to use a text editor of your choice. It does not need to be* `vi`, *but you do need to edit the file as* `root`.
2. Find the line that reads:

   ```
   load-module module-udev-detect
   ```

   Append `tsched=0` to the line so that it looks like this:

   ```
   load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
   ```
3. Restart PulseAudio:

   ```
   systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
   ```

Hopefully this solution will work for you as well

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I still get no audio.  I still only have the one playback device (the 3.5 mm jack) when I do a `aplay -l` and in `alsamixer`